# How do I disable Pods/Elementor while using Ninja Forms?

Tags: pods-framework, deactivation, plugin-ninja-forms

There's a conflict when using Pods, Elementor, and Ninja Forms together. This is a known issue by Ninja but the other players are uncooperative and Ninja is still a little ways out on a real fix. The conflict manifests by displaying a blank page when trying to edit a Ninja Form. At least in theory, if I can just disable the functionality of Pods or Elementor while I'm editing forms, I should be fine. I've attempted to deactivate_plugins on admin_init and then reactivating for other pages. That didn't seem to do the trick (at least how I did it). I've attempted to disable it with Plugin Organizer but was not able to figure out a way to make that work for this either. It seems like there should be a simple answer to this that's just evading me.

Comment: You're going to have to work with the plugins' support teams. WPSE doesn't provide third-party support.

Comment: @PatJ I'm not asking anybody to support anything here. I'm asking if somebody has a good workaround that I can put in outside of these 3 plugins that will remove the conflict.